# math-mode: \vec and vector vector norm: Vector arrownot covered

Tags: math-mode, vector

When using vector arrow notation (\vec) combined with \lVert and \rVert, the norm won't cover the vector arrow if a capital letter issued for the vector, but instead cover extra "white space" below the letter.

Also `\left\lVert # \right\rVert` or `\Big\lVert # \Big\rVert` don't fix the problem, as they drastically increase vertical size covering much more white space above and below the vector. I would like to use this notation also in text, which is why vertical size matters a lot.

An optimal solution would be achieved if it was possible to simply shift the "||" upwards s.t. they cover the vector arrow and the least amount of white space below the letter, is that possible?

Example:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    
    \begin{document}
    
    \[
    \lVert \vec{A} \rVert = \left\lVert \vec{A} \right\rVert = \Big\lVert \vec{A} \Big\rVert
    \]
    
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately not, it's equivalent to \left\lVert \vec{A} \right\rVert.

Comment: The starred form is equivalent to `\left`/`\right`. You can pass the manual size as optional parameter. Anyway you want `\big`, not `\Big`.

Comment: `\big` does the job, thanks!